# Determining the cardinality of a set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

If you have a set that looks like $S_1 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ I understand the cardinality of the set is $5$.

What about if you have a set of sets so

$S_1=\{S_2,S_3,S_4\}$
where,

$S_2=\{1,2,3\}$

$S_3=\{1,2\}$

$S_4=\{1\}$.

For the cardinality of $S_1$ do you count all the elements of the included sets so the answer would be $6$ or do you just count the number in the $S_1$ so it would be $3$.

Comment: The set of the members of the members of $S$ is denoted $\cup S$ and is not often  equal to $S$ and often has a  different cardinal'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the latter, i.e. we just count the number of elements of $S1$, which is 3.